# Mysql Joins with nested Select

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I am trying to get the total of all orders of each seller per year, month, and day using this sql. I am still wrapping my head around joins, but from what I know i thought this should work

```
SELECT sellers.username, sellers.registerDate, sellers.sellerid,
orders.orderPrice, orders.orderDate, orders.sellerid,
count(orders.orderPrice) AS products, SUM( orders.orderPrice ) AS total,
FROM  `sellers` 
JOIN
`orders`,
(SELECT SUM( orders.orderPrice ) FROM  `orders` WHERE YEAR( orderDate ) = YEAR( CURDATE( ) ) ) AS year,
(SELECT SUM( orders.orderPrice ) FROM  `orders` WHERE MONTH( orderDate ) = MONTH( CURDATE( ) ) ) AS month,
(SELECT SUM( orders.orderPrice ) FROM  `orders` WHERE orderDate = CURDATE() ) AS day
ON orders.sellerid = sellers.sellerid
GROUP BY sellers.username
HAVING total > 0
ORDER BY total desc
LIMIT 0 , 4
```

But it gives me an error (#1064 - near 'ON orders.sellerid = sellers.sellerid GROUP BY sellers.username HAVING' at line 9)

Comment: `JOIN single_(derived)_table_reference ON whatever`, not `JOIN multiple,table,references,with,an ON clause` ?

Comment: If you use explicit notation (TableA JOIN TableB) you must use ON clause after JOIN. If you use comma to link your table, you must put in WHERE clause the condition to link your table (without using ON clause)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You need to set ON clause on every join table not only the lastone.
```

Regards

```
JOIN
    `orders` ON ??? = ???,
    (SELECT SUM( orders.orderPrice ) FROM  `orders` WHERE YEAR( orderDate ) = YEAR(   CURDATE( ) ) ) AS year ON orders.sellerid = sellers.sellerid,
    (SELECT SUM( orders.orderPrice ) FROM  `orders` WHERE MONTH( orderDate ) = MONTH( CURDATE( ) ) ) AS month ON orders.sellerid = sellers.sellerid,
    (SELECT SUM( orders.orderPrice ) FROM  `orders` WHERE orderDate = CURDATE() ) AS day 
         ON orders.sellerid = sellers.sellerid
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But what you showed me still is not working. It still gives me the same error (#1064 near 'ON orders.sellerid = sellers.sellerid, (SELECT SUM( orders.orderPrice ) FROM' at line 7) after the first statement in the join. Any idea why?